# Considering size of an SQL Server DB / Table partition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, partition

The maximum possible database size of a SQL Server 2012 Web Edition is 524PB. What if I have tables partitioned in it? Can each table hold 524PB of data or should the sum of all table sizes (i.e. the actual db size) be 524PB?

Answer (score 1):

Database objects include objects such as tables, views, stored procedures, user-defined functions, triggers, rules, defaults, and constraints.

Then the sum of all object must be <= 524,272 terabytes

[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)